# Is this Java class declaration correct?

Tags: java, inner-classes

I want to build `Data` main class with subclasses `DataClass1`(with own subclass `Item`) and `DataClass2` (with own subclass `Item1`).

```
public class Data{

        public  List<DataClass1> dataClass1List = new ArrayList<DataClass1>();
        public  List<DataClass2> dataClass2List = new ArrayList<DataClass2>();


        public class DataClass1{

            public String name;   
            public  List<Item> itemList = new ArrayList<Item>();

            public class Item{
                public String n1;          
                public String n2;               
                public String n3;              
            }

        }


        public class DataClass2{

            public String name; 
            public  List<Item1> item1List = new ArrayList<Item1>();

            public class Item1{
                public String n5;
                public String n6;   
            }

        }

    }
```

When I want to fill main class `Data` I use this code:

```
Data data = new Data();
Item itm = new Item;
itm.n1="1";
itm.n2="2";
itm.n3="3";
data.dataClass1List.itemList.add(itm);
```

and same for dataClass2List

All sub classes must be public

Is there better way to declare and filling up my class `Data`

Thanks!!!

p.s. Data class and its sub classes contain only variables not methods!

Comment: This is really not a very object-oriented approach. A (very first) step in the right direction would be to change the names of the classes to reflect what the classes represent (as opposed to the generic word 'data') and then implement methods from there.

Comment: @WirthLuce I change names for this question only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Some suggesions:**

- You should use getter and setter to access the different fields.

```
public class SomeClass {

    private String name;
    [...]

    public void setName(String name) {this.name = name;}
    public String getName() {return name;}
    [...]
}
```

- Since the Data classes are public, do they need to be inner class?

To fix this you would need to move the different public class to different files.

- All internal lists could be made `final`.

```
public final List<Item> itemList = new ArrayList<Item>();
```

- You could make a constructor for the class Item.

```
public class Item {
    public Item(String n1,String n2,String n3)  {
        this.n1 = n1;
        this.n2 = n2;
        this.n3 = n3;
    }
    [...]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be confusing some concepts here.

There are no subclasses in your code.  `DataClass1` and `DataClass2` are [inner classes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_class) of `Data`, `Item` is an inner class of `DataClass1` and `Item1` is an inner class of `DataClass2`.

There's no visible need for them to be inner classes, and you're best off avoiding inner classes until you're sure you need them and likely until you know Java a bit better.

With these as inner classes, your proposed usage of them will not work, as they're non-static inner classes, and can only be created within the context of an **instance** of the outer class.

With the class definitions as they are, a translation of your posted usage would be approximately

```
Data data = new Data();
DataClass1 dc1 = data.new DataClass1();
Item itm = dc1.new Item();
itm.n1="1";
itm.n2="2";
itm.n3="3";
dc1.itemList.add(itm);
data.dataClass1List.add(dc1);
```

But this is really quite bad (and it may contain mistakes - I have bothered trying to compile it).  Having classes with only fields and no methods, and adding data in this way is not a very object-oriented approach at all.

As WirthLuce noted in a comment, you should change the names to represent something in your domain, and create methods to make them do something appropriate rather than just holding data that is manipulated from outside.